AES S-box as simple algebraic transformation
The next matrix represents the Rijndael S-box according to wikipedia and other sources
$$\begin{bmatrix}s_0\\s_1\\s_2\\s_3\\s_4\\s_5\\s_6\\s_7\end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    b_0\\ b_1\\ b_2\\ b_3\\ b_4\\ b_5\\ b_6\\ b_7
  \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\\ 1\\ 0
  \end{bmatrix}.$$
The $b$ are the coefficients the inverse of the input as elements of $\mathbb F_{256}.$ My question is based on the fact that the matrix is circulant. Can't the same transformation be represented as a multiplication by $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 \in \mathbb F_{128}?$ And if so why are the operations typically described by this more complex notation?

I think this is true. It's probably the reason why the following notation is used.
$$s = \left(b \times 31_{10} \mod{257_{10}}\right) \oplus 99_{10}$$
There's no way that the polynomial that defines the field
$$1+x+x^3+x^4+x^8=0$$ gets translated to 257, though.
And in the AES page it is explained that

To avoid attacks based on simple algebraic properties, the S-box is constructed by combining the inverse function with an invertible affine transformation.

But in this case the result is an algebraically simple function of the input, so I think it would not make sense to use this affine transformation instead of a different one that doesn't have this simple structure.

Your $b$-vector has eight bits, so why do you claim it represents an element of  $\Bbb{F}{128}$ instead of $\Bbb{F}{256}=GF(2^8)$?

And multiplication by $x$ amounts to multiplication by the matrix
$$\pmatrix{
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\cr
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\cr
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\cr
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&1\cr
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1\cr
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\cr
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\cr
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\cr}.$$
Assuming that a monomial basis is used (and the $b_i$s are the coordinates w.r.t. to it. It is not circulant. The coefficients of defining polynomial appear in the last column (sans $x^8$).

@JyrkiLahtonen
Thanks. It's obvious now that you say that. The circulant matrix would  represent multiplication by this element if we were working in $\frac{\mathbb F_2[x]}{x^8-1}$,  wich is not a field. And 128 is just a mistake.

If $a$ is an element of $GF(256)$, then $a^{254}$ will result in the inverse, but there is no real reason to do this. If this is done in software, it could be done via a lookup table. For hardware, to reduce gate count, the field is usually mapped (matrix multiply) to $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$, inverted, mapped back. Mapping back could include the affine step.

The notation
$$s = \left(b \times 31_{10} \bmod{257_{10}}\right) \oplus 99_{10}$$
does correspond to a polynomial multiplication of $b$ times $f = 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 \in \mathbb F_{2}[x].$ Here $f$ is denoted as $31.$ But unlike the previous operation that was carried out in $\mathbb F_{256}$ defined by the polynomial $1+x+x^3+x^4+x^8=0,$ this time the operation is carried out modulo $x^8+1,$ so that's where the $257$ comes from. The addition of $99$ corresponds to the addition of the vector.
In short, even though both obtaining an inverse in the field $\mathbb F_{256}$ and multiplying by $f$ modulo $x^8+1$ are both algebraically simple operations, their composition isn't because they depend on a particular representation of elements of $\mathbb F_{256}$ as polynomials.
I leave the question just in case someone else has the same doubt, even though it's clear that circulant matrices only represent polynomial multiplication modulo $x^8-1.$
